# Secondary Live Tile action

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a simple lap counter app and is it possible to:

Have a secondary tile that displays the lap count and when clicked updates the count, but stays on the start screen.  I do not want the users to have to navigate to my app then click a button to update the count then navigate back to the start screen.

Can I just have the secondary tile run some code to update itself and either leave the user at the start screen or return them quickly to the start screen (as if they never left)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have control on what happens after user clicks on secondary tile.
Once secondary tile is clicked, it launches the app. You cant avoid that.

You can close the app, after incrementing the count programatically.

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

Thanks